# How should I rename my account's name in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, users, accounts

I made mistake typing account's name before installation of Ubuntu.
I need to change this name, but I can't find clear explanation and step-by-step procedure.

Also, why doesn't Ubuntu change the name of account after editing it in `System Settings->User Accounts` ?? Even Win'98 had explicit ways to change administrator username!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new user with the correct details and admin rights, log out and log in again with the new user and then copy your old data if any and delete the old user.

Alternatively, you can install gnome-system-tools or kuser to do this. These packages provide more advanced GUIs to deal with user accounts. However, use them with CAUTION.
You will still need to be logged in with another admin account to apply the changes for the account you want to change.

Comment: Unfortunately, It is not good because of presence of self-written libs and software. They shall be broken by simple copying of user directory.